# How to vectorize the following, the append is probably the bottleneck

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following dataframe with two columns `c1` and `c2`, I want to add a new column `c3` based on the following logic, what I have works but is slow, can anyone suggest a way to vectorize this?

- Must be grouped based on `c1` and `c2`, then for each group, the new column `c3` must be populated sequentially from `values` where the key is the value of `c1` and each "sub group" will have subsequent values, IOW `values[value_of_c1][idx]`, where `idx` is the "sub group", example below
- The first group `(1, 'a')`, here `c1` is `1`, the "sub group" `"a"` index is `0` (first sub group of 1) so `c3` for all rows in this group is `values[1][0]`
- The second group `(1, 'b')` here `c1` is still `1` but "sub group" is `"b"` so index `1` (second sub group of 1) so for all rows in this group `c3` is `values[1][1]`
- The third group `(2, 'y')` here `c1` is now `2`, "sub group" is `"a"` and the index is `0` (first sub group of 2), so for all rows in this group `c3` is `values[2][0]`
- And so on
- `values` will have the necessary elements to satisfy this logic.

Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "c1": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "c2": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z"],
    }
)
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
values = {1: ["a1", "a2"], 2: ["b1", "b2"]}
for i, j in df.groupby("c1"):
    for idx, (k, l) in enumerate(j.groupby("c2")):
        l["c3"] = values[i][idx]
        new_df = new_df.append(l)
```

Output (works but my code is slow)

```
    c1 c2  c3
0    1  a  a1
1    1  a  a1
2    1  a  a1
3    1  b  a2
4    1  b  a2
5    1  b  a2
6    2  y  b1
7    2  y  b1
8    2  y  b1
9    2  z  b2
10   2  z  b2
11   2  z  b2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using another library, you basically need to label encode within your groups:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

def le(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(LabelEncoder().fit_transform(x),index=x.index)
    
df['idx'] = df.groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(le)

df['c3'] = df.apply(lambda x:values[x['c1']][x['idx']],axis=1)

    c1 c2  idx  c3
0    1  a    0  a1
1    1  a    0  a1
2    1  a    0  a1
3    1  b    1  a2
4    1  b    1  a2
5    1  b    1  a2
6    2  y    0  b1
7    2  y    0  b1
8    2  y    0  b1
9    2  z    1  b2
10   2  z    1  b2
11   2  z    1  b2
```

Otherwise it's a matter of using `pd.Categorical` , same concept as above, just that you convert within each group, the column into a category and just pull out the code:

```
def le(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(pd.Categorical(x).codes,index=x.index)
```

Comment: thanks for the alternate solution, I have timed this using the `pd.Categorical` suggestion and it appears to be faster than what I have

Comment: whilst I try to understand this, can you let me know if this depends on the `values` data I have shown or its a general solution? as in, if the values of `values` are shuffled and are different, this would still work? this does not take into account the toy example's pattern right?

Comment: nvm, it works, `[x['c1']][x['idx']]` I thought this was merging some columns, but I failed to notice the `values` in `values[x['c1']][x['idx']]`, thanks again, this works

Comment: cool, nice you figured that out..  yeah the dictionary part is a bit hard on the eye

Answer (score 1):

```py
In [203]: a = pd.DataFrame([[k, value, idx] for k,v in values.items() for idx,value in enumerate(v)], columns=['c1', 'c3', 'gr'])
     ...: b = df.assign(gr=df.groupby(['c1']).transform(lambda x: (x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())- 1))
     ...: print(b)
     ...: b.merge(a).drop(columns='gr')
     ...:
# b
    c1 c2  gr
0    1  a   0
1    1  a   0
2    1  a   0
3    1  b   1
4    1  b   1
5    1  b   1
6    2  y   0
7    2  y   0
8    2  y   0
9    2  z   1
10   2  z   1
11   2  z   1
Out[203]:
    c1 c2  c3
0    1  a  a1
1    1  a  a1
2    1  a  a1
3    1  b  a2
4    1  b  a2
5    1  b  a2
6    2  y  b1
7    2  y  b1
8    2  y  b1
9    2  z  b2
10   2  z  b2
11   2  z  b2
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, can you explain this? I will gladly accept it

Comment: 1. `df.assign(gr=...)` is the same as `df['gr'] = ...`

Comment: I am new to pandas, but based on your effort, how much of a difficult problem was this?

Comment: @Valencia I can't speak for Asish, problems such as these are fairly simple to solve for more experienced pandas users.

Comment: I timed this code using timeit, but why is this slower than mine, this looks completely vectorized and fine to me